# Selenium Python NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, selenium

**Background:**

So I have very little coding knowledge, I have tried to learn coding several times through guides and youtube tutorials but never got very far in my learning. This time around I am trying a different approach, of simply having an idea and doing it.

I am trying to make a program interact with the website [fitbit](https://www.fitbit.com/settings/profile). Very simply it needs to login and change the email of my account.

I have successfully used Selenium python to login and access the settings page, but I cannot interact with any of the elements beyond this.

Once the program has made it to the settings page it needs to click the "Change Email Address"

Then fill in the form and click submit. That is all I need the program to do.

**My code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


chromedriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/chromedriver.exe')
browser = chromedriver


browser.get('https://www.fitbit.com/settings/profile')
browser.implicitly_wait(20)
username = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/fieldset/dl/dd[1]/input')
username.click()
username.send_keys('Email')
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/fieldset/dl/dd[2]/input')
password.click()
password.send_keys('Password')

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[1]/button').click()
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
#browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember798"]/div[3]/div[2]/button').click()
new_email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember1077"]')
new_email.click()
new_email.send_keys('New Email')
confirm_new_email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember1107"]')
confirm_new_email.click()
confirm_new_email.send_keys('New Email')
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember1119"]')
password.click()
password.send_keys('Password')
#browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ember832 > div:nth-child(4) > div.column.medium-5.change-email-button-container > button').click()
#browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember748"]/div[3]/div[2]').click()
```

**My Error:**

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51658/devtools/browser/12ae1773-a1f7-473f-8128-32f2090202fc
[12820:7500:1215/095935.812:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(257)] Failed to create shader cache entry: -2
[12820:7500:1215/095959.060:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(257)] Failed to create shader cache entry: -2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "looptest.py", line 25, in <module>
    new_email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember1077"]')
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_
by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']

  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_resp
onse
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"
method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ember1077"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 1
0.0.17134 x86_64)
```

I appreciate the code is messy, and I plan to tidy things up and add in if statements, trys and everything else once the program actually works.

**Solutions:**

1. I have tried to make the browser wait for the elements to load.
2. I have tried fiddling around with the iframe command, I do not believe the first button is on a different iframe, but the second part maybe.
3. I have tried using xpath, and tried using the CSS selector command as well.

**The HTML:**

[IMAGE OF SETTINGS PAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0ZMP.png)

Above is an image of the settings page, I want to click the button circled in red

Here is the xpath: `//*[@id="ember815"]/div[3]/div[2]/button`

sol the element 100% exists.

[HTML OF BUTTON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuHtG.png)

There is a screenshot of the inspect of the element.

[CHANGE EMAIL FIELDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAazA.png)

Once the button has been click this box will appear and I need to then fill in these fields.

[THE HTML OF THE NEW EMAIL FIELD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd4b6.png)

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. I know there is a quite a bit of Javascript on this page, and I reckon that is my problem. The Javascript is making it so I cannot interact with these elements but I am unsure why.

**UPDATE 1.0**

A user suggest I screenshot all the parts I am unsure about using the command

```
browser.save_screenshot('error2.png')
```

Interestingly the screenshot is provides is blank. [SEE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7DrN.png)

**Update 2.0**

Thank you for the responses so far, I have implemented the suggestion.

I implemented the this line of code

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="button change-email-button"]').click()
```

and it has progressed the program so it takes me to this stage.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3reB.png)

Now I am facing the same problem with filling out the form.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "looptest.py", line 28, in <module>
    new_email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('(//input[@data-test-qa="new-email"])[2]')
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_
by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element

    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_resp
onse
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"
method":"xpath","selector":"(//input[@data-test-qa="new-email"])[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 1
0.0.17134 x86_64)
```

I have added waits and things, but still having no luck

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="button change-email-button"]').click()
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
#new_email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember1077"]')
new_email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('(//input[@data-test-qa="new-email"])[2]')
```

Comment: you should try taking screenshots in every step that you are not sure about.

Comment: Are the screenshots I have provided not sufficient?

Comment: sorry I was just suggesting how you could debug it better. I am not trying to answer this question.

Comment: Oh its, fine! I feel like there are enough screenshots. But we will see if others are able to help!

Comment: I am talking about [this](https://pythonspot.com/selenium-take-screenshot/), not about your shared screenshots of the site.

Comment: OOOOOOH, what to see if the browser can see the element. Good idea will try now!

Comment: I have done, as you suggest elRuLL and the screenshot is blank? So there is my problem. The page loads fine for me, as in I can watch the browsers actions and it loads fine. So why is the page black for the program?

Comment: maybe selenium didn't load it yet? you'll have to debug better and add more waits and sleeps everywhere I'd suggest

Comment: Adding longer waits, doesn't work? Do you think this is an authentication problem. And thats why selenium cannot view the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to the users that responded. We have a solution

Here the key fact as @ewwink correctly said, I failed to notice that the elements I was trying to access had dynamic ids.

I managed to fix this issue by typing out my own xpath and came up with the following:

```
//*[@data-test-qa="new-email"]

//*[@data-test-qa="confirm-new-email"]

//*[@data-test-qa="password-for-email-change"]
```

These work each time the program is run!

Answer (score 0):

it seem the `ID` is dynamic try use the folowing Xpath

```
# Change Email Address button
//button[@class="button change-email-button"]

# email
(//input[@data-test-qa="new-email"])[2]

# confirm email
(//input[@data-test-qa="confirm-new-email"])[2]

# password
(//input[@data-test-qa="password-for-email-change"])[2]
```

after clicking the `Change Email` button you need to wait until form popup appear

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Trying now. Any reason why the screenshot the browser takes is appearing to be blank? See the update!

Comment: for screenshot try with full path or `browser.get_screenshot_as_file('D:/error2.png')`

Comment: your suggestion works partially. It opens the change email window, but I am getting the same problem with the email, confirm email, and password.

Comment: I tell you above it need to wait until the form appear.

Comment: @NiallMcGibney try sleeping or waiting for an element in the form to appear before proceeding with the login call

Comment: I have added a wait but it still does not seem to work?

Comment: update you questions with the error. and here how to test the Xpath in chrome [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Khf.jpg)

Comment: updated the question! See new information please @ewwink

Comment: I know the problem, as you said, the element is dynamic so the xpath that google provides changes everytime its loaded. However the ones you have supplied also do not work for some reason. Other than the first one!

Comment: `@data-test-qa` is not dynamic I see it in your image above, please try the xpath in chrome and remove `[2]`,